# Display internal RSS Feed in SharePoint Online

Tags: rss

I need to display a page on my SharePoint Online as an RSS feed on another page, on the same site. The idea is that I can update the data in the source page and the RSS feed will display the data. Trouble is I have tried the RSS Viewer web part and the XML web part, but neither work.

I get "Forbidden" when I use the RSS viewer and "Cannot display" for the XML feed. I have no idea where to go from here. RSS is enabled at the site level.

Any ideas how I can configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PageViewer webpart and load the original page.

Alternatively you can store the Page data in a List and use it to display it in both the pages.

**Based on comment - How to reload a div with TXT file content every 30 minutes**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 1000 * 60 * 30; //value in millisecond           
    loadContent();
});

var loadContent = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://somesite/library/sometext.txt",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#news').html(data);
            setTimeout(function() {
                loadContent();
            }, interval);
        }
    });
};

<div id="news"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a working display of raw text using the Content Editor web part displaying a text file. Trouble is users have to press F5 to see the new content. Is there a way to get a live update so it appears instantly in the web part when I add data to the text file?

Comment: The text file will be loaded on the client side and it will never know of any changes. Do you really want to go this route? Your only option is to write some JavaScript that polls the text file for any changes and if find any changes then reload the page.

Comment: Well, it's meant to be a live status section, so we can see notices throughout the day. I guess people will just have to refresh the page.

Comment: See my edited answer.. this is just an idea.. hope it works for you.. you need to add jQuery to your page + copy the content to a text file.. and reference that in the Content editor link property...

Comment: Where do I put the Javascript code? When I add it to the page source in <script> tags it gets removed by Sharepoint.

Comment: Ok sorry I think I understand, I put the JS in a new file and reference that in the CEWP property. Will the data get loaded into the webpart or another area of the page?

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint Online and the introduction of Modern Site pages, users now have the ability to add the [Modern RSS Web Part](https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-online-rss-feed-web-part-office-365) directly to site pages.

This webpart currently has limited functionality compared to it's predecessor, however, it is a good start for pulling a feed of external content onto a SharePoint page. The only major difference with this version is that you are limited in your ability to customize the layout or format.